# How to mock bean in interceptor of Spring Mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, mocking, interceptor

I want to test spring mvc controller, and this controller have an interceptor with a bean such as UserService, i want to mock this bean, How should i do ?

configuration is as following:

`<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/account/p-bind-verify.do" />
    <bean class="com.web.interceptor.HttpBasicAuthInterceptor">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>`

in my mind, the UserService is singleton, and i create a mock UserService object, and set the object to UserService in the context, but it does't work.

Comment: Is the test going to be an integration test using Spring MVC Test?

Comment: yes, i use MockMvc class:
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions you could follow in order to mock the `userService`.

One solution is to run the test using a different [Spring Profile](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) in which you would specify a mock bean for `userService`.

Another solution would be to use [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) that insert mocks of beans into the Spring context.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(HttpBasicAuthInterceptor,"userService",new MockUserService());
}
```